# Configure a Netgear WN111 wireless usb adapter on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, usb

since my PCMCIA card doesn't work anymore on my Ubuntu (I asked another question about that), I bought a USB wifi adapter, the Netgear WN111.

I thought it would work with Ubuntu, but nothing happens when I plug it in.

What steps should I take to configure it ?

Comment: Nervimind, I brought it back to the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=859481

http://georgia.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=893879

Sounds like the only way people have had some success is through the ndiswrapper.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=807225

Comment: Owwww :( that's too bad. I thought Ubuntu would have no problems with a usb adapter.

Comment: I would never assume something works in linux without explicit manufactor support or some google research before a purchase.

Comment: Yeah, I know... I went to the store right before closing, and didn't really have time to do research. That'll teach me.